# Excel - Split Cell Into Multiple Columns Based On Everty Nth Occurence

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to do this:
I have a Column where each row may have a different amount of html-formatted emails and a line break.

For example:

**Column A**

```
<a href=mailto:'test@test.com'>test@test.com</a><br/>, <a href=mailto:'test2@test.com'>test2@test.com</a><br/>
```

Some rows may have one email, some may have many.

I would like to create a function where I could split the cell into mulitple columns, putting only 3 or 4 emails in new columns. So if there is one-three emails, it could stay in its column, but if there are four, the fourth would be moved to a new column, if there were five, the fourth and fifth would be put into a new column together.

Comment: Stack Over flow is not a code for me site.  It is a site where people come with specific question about code that is not working.  This is too broad for this site.

Comment: I may have overcomplicated this with my answer by not realizing what you were actually trying to do - just use Text to Columns and split using comma - I believe that's what you're looking for.